# ESLint: Prevent Arrow Function Use in Javascript (I grew up calling them Lambda Functions)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a JavaScript project that I'd like to prevent the use of lambda expression functions =>.

Is there an ESLint rule I can use to help enforce this?

I'm working with Visual Studio Code.

(I've searched and tested and guessed for a couple hours...)

Comment: They're called "arrow functions", not lambda, that might help your search.

Comment: See if something here might help: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible to use `eslint-plugin-es` with `es/no-arrow-functions` rule. Reference [here](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-es/blob/master/docs/rules/no-arrow-functions.md)

P.S. it's not lambda, but arrow functions :)